# Error when logging in with Machinist in Shoulda test

Tags: authlogic, shoulda, machinist

I am having some trouble getting the right usage of Machinist and Shoulda in my testing.

Here is my test:

```
 context "on POST method rating" do
p = Product.make
u = nil
setup do
  u = login_as
  post :vote, :rating => 3, :id => p
end

should "set rating for product to 3" do
  assert_equal p.get_user_vote(u), 3
end
```

And here's my blueprints:

```
 Sham.login { Faker::Internet.user_name }
Sham.name { Faker::Lorem.words}
Sham.email { Faker::Internet.email}
Sham.body { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(2)}

User.blueprint do
 login
 password "testpass"
 password_confirmation { password }
 email
end

Product.blueprint do
 name {Sham.name}
 user {User.make}
end
```

And my authentication test helper:

```
def login_as(u = nil)
   u ||= User.make()
   @controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(u)
   u
 end
```

The error I get is:

```
/home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1090:in `save_without_dirty!': Validation failed: Login has already been taken, Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)                                                         
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:87:in `save_without_transactions!'                                                             
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'                                                                          
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'                                
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'                                                                    
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'                                                                          
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
       from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/machinist-1.0.6/lib/machinist/active_record.rb:55:in `make'
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/test/blueprints.rb:37
       from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/machinist-1.0.6/lib/machinist.rb:77:in `generate_attribute_value'
       from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/machinist-1.0.6/lib/machinist.rb:46:in `method_missing'
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/test/blueprints.rb:37
       from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/machinist-1.0.6/lib/machinist.rb:20:in `instance_eval'
       from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/machinist-1.0.6/lib/machinist.rb:20:in `run'
       from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/machinist-1.0.6/lib/machinist/active_record.rb:53:in `make'
       from ./test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:25:in `__bind_1269805681_945912'
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.10.2/lib/shoulda/context.rb:293:in `call'
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.10.2/lib/shoulda/context.rb:293:in `merge_block'
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.10.2/lib/shoulda/context.rb:288:in `initialize'
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.10.2/lib/shoulda/context.rb:169:in `new'
       from /home/jason/moderndarwin/vendor/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.10.2/lib/shoulda/context.rb:169:in `context'
       from ./test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:24
```

I can't figure out what it is I'm doing wrong... I have tested the login_as with my auth (Authlogic) in my user_controller testing.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've got a partial solution... I've solved the problem above, but the should_redirect_to function is still giving me fits...

This is my new test code:

```
context "on POST method rating" do

   setup do
     @u = login_as
     @p1 = Product.make
     @p2 = Product.make # Make a second product that we'll show after rating the first
     post :vote, :rating => 3, :id => @p1
   end

   should "set rating for product to 3" do
     assert_equal @p1.get_user_vote(@u), 3
   end

   should_redirect_to("product page") {show_product_url(:id => @p2)}    
 end
```

And my new error:

```
response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/products/555660218> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/products>.
```

Any ideas where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Is your controller redirecting to products_url?

Side note: you shouldn't use random data (Faker) for any validation that requires uniqueness. That's what Factory Girl's sequences are for. I assume Machinist has something similar.

Comment: Here is what my controller is doing:
 def vote
    Vote.do_vote # do some voting logic
    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => current_user.next_product(session[:tags])
  end

Comment: What I don't understand is that the code works properly when I test in a browser, just not when using the test suite. I've also tried rewriting the controller redirect to match my test:
  def vote
    redirect_to show_product_url(current_user.next_product(session[:tags]))
  end

Comment: Further, I tried mocking to eliminate some unknowns:
  context "on POST method rating" do

    setup do
      @u = login_as
      @p1 = Product.make
      @p2 = Product.make # Make a second product that we'll show after rating the first
      post :vote, :rating => 3, :id => @p1
      @u.expects(:next_product).returns(@p2)
    end
    
    should_redirect_to("product page") {show_product_url(:id => @p2)}
  end

Still the same error.